# Linking Allegro 5 with Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, shared-libraries, allegro5

I've been struggling for a couple of hours now trying to link Allegro 5 to Eclipse on Ubuntu. And yes, I've been searching for it but I must be missing something really simple and you guys will surely find it right away, so please help me out...

I create the project like this:
[image]

And when I try to link any library (example below)
[image]

I get this error when compiling my program!
[image]

And here is a pic of the relevant folders with the correctly compiled libraries:
[image]

---

**EDIT:**

If you are struggling with this as well, all I had to do was very simple, you just need to add these to you libraries:
[image]

here is the list so you can just copy and paste it:

allegro
allegro_acodec
allegro_audio
allegro_color
allegro_dialog
allegro_font
allegro_image
allegro_main
allegro_memfile
allegro_physfs
allegro_primitives
allegro_ttf

Comment: -lallegro. No pathname.

Comment: @bmargulies sorry, can you please explain better what I need to do?

Comment: replace -l/usr/something/liballegro.so with -lallegro .

Comment: @bmargulies but if I do so, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/Hr2lCjH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get out of eclipse and just use the command line until you have this sorted. Eclipse is just a complex way to obfuscating the command line.

To link a .so, you need:

- -LpathToLibrary
- -lnameOfLibrary, with 'lib' and '.so' stripped off.

If your library is sitting in /usr/lib, which is suggested by what you are trying, then you don't need the -L at all. If the name is 'liballegro5.so', you'll need -lallegro5.

I recommend:

find /usr -name liballegro.so -print

if the answer is '/usr/lib/liballegro.so', then all you need is -lallegro.

If the answer is /SOMETHINGELSE/liballegro.so, then you need -L/SOMETHINGELSE/.

If you don't find liballegro, then you need to figure out if it's actually liballegro5.so.

You can also stop using -L and -l and just put the entire path of the .so in there.

Comment: thanks for the help! I managed to compile the program using the command line like this `g++ main.cpp -o test \`pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0\``. But I would like to be able to use eclipse to compile since I have bigger projects with lots of source files.. Do you have any hints of what I could be missing to be able to compile via eclipse now we know the command that successfully compiled it on the command line?

Comment: So, what does that pkg-config command print when you just run it? Whatever it prints, you can add to the eclipse config.

Comment: thank you for all the help! I finally managed to compile using eclipse! Instead of linking /usr/lib/allegro*.so I just need to add the names, no path at all: http://i.imgur.com/5JIAiWh.png